# "have drunk enough already" / "have already drunk enough"

Tags: sentence-construction

> You **have drunk enough already**.
>
> You **have already drunk enough**.

As I know it, the commonest place for "already" is after "have". But in this case, there is the opposite situation. Could you explain it?

Comment: To me, the first sentence carries a (more) negative connotation of disapproval/intolerance/annoyance since "enough already" is a fixed expression to express that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Grammarly on the placement of adverbs:

> Place adverbs as close as possible to the words they are supposed to
> modify. Putting the adverb in the wrong spot can produce an awkward
> sentence at best and completely change the meaning at worst. Be
> especially careful about the word only, which is one of the most often
> misplaced modifiers. Consider the difference between these two
> sentences:
>
> Phillip only fed the cat.
>
> Phillip fed only the cat.

In your first example, the adverb "already" is placed nearest to "enough" (in this case, another adverb) emphasising the latter. In your second example, it is placed nearest to "drunk".

Both are correct, but emphasis is key here.

The first example, in which "enough" is in the "spotlight", insinuates something that might relate to a past period of someone's life, given the Merriam-Webster's definition of enough (see entry 2 of 3, for the adverb):

> in or to a degree or quantity that satisfies or that is sufficient or
> necessary for satisfaction : sufficiently

The second example, which rather emphasises the verb "drunk", would tend to be used when someone is "fed up" of drinking, in a more present/current/active context than in the first example.

This being said, people might always write without paying proper attention to these types of details, conveying the wrong meaning via the misuse of emphasis. It is up to you to deduce whether the quoted text you provided was properly structured or not, in accordance to its context.

---

### References:

1. Grammarly Staff. (n.d.). What Is an Adverb? Grammarly Blog. Retrieved January 28, 2022, from https://www.grammarly.com/blog/adverb/
2. The Merriam-Webster Online Dictionary. (n.d.). Enough Definition & Meaning. Merriam-Webster. Retrieved January 28, 2022, from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/enough. Entry 2 of 3, definition 1.